# How to modify jQuery Chosen selected text

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I currently have a `select` which shows options as

```
<option>{{ tag.name }} ({{ tag.count }})</option>
```

However, I would like that when the user selects the option, in the selected options, only the `name` is visible and not the last part. Think of how stack* shows the tag count but hides it when you select it.

Ideas? Thanks.

Edit: Sorry for not being clear. In [chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/), when you select an option, a textbox fills up with the selected data. I want **that** text to be modified, not the one on the `<select>`!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, sorry. Do you want to change the value of the option?

Comment: @LonelyWebCrawler if the option says "Music (25)", when selected, I want the text input to only show "Music", ie strip everything in parenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: For *your* edit, if the option elements have a `value` attribute set to the text you want to use try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("select").change(function() {
        $("input").val( $(this).val() );
    }).change();
});​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CdKGT/2/

Or if you can't use the `value` attribute for some reason and want to extract the text from what is displayed:

```
$("select").change(function() {
    $("input").val( $("option:selected",this).text().replace(/ \(\d+\)$/,"") );
}).change();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CdKGT/3/

Obviously you'd use an id or class to identify the select and input rather than just `$("select")` and `$("input")`, but you get the idea.

MY ORIGINAL ANSWER (for my interpretation of your original question):

You could do something like this:

```
​<select>
<option value="css" data-count="1">css 1</option>
<option value="html" data-count="55">html 55</option>
<option value="java" data-count="37">java 37</option>
<option value="javascript" data-count="20">javascript 20</option>
<option value="jquery" data-count="12">jquery 12</option>
</select>
```

And then:

```
​$(document).ready(function() {
    $("select").change(function() {
        $(this).find("option").html(function(){ return this.value + " " +
                                                       $(this).attr("data-count"); });
        $("option:selected",this).html(this.value);
    }).change();
});​​​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CdKGT/1/

(Obviously you can optimise the function a bit by caching the jQuery objects and so forth, but I kept it simple for proof of concept.)

Answer (score 0):

**Chosen does not support the functionality you want**

Kinda sorta got a workaround... however it does not consistently work because of how chosen does stuff internally.  http://jsfiddle.net/2hHYh/

Chosen does not always fire a change event when an option is selected however it will still set the display text to whatever is clicked. :O  This is particularly evident when clicking the same option again.

Comment: This does not work for Chosen. I already use this. Please read my edit. :)

Comment: Edited my original answer, chosen does not do what you want apparently.

Comment: However thanks for bringing the plugin to my attention.  It is quite nice despite the lack of options.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$("select").change(
function()
{
    var value = $("option:selected").html()
    var new_value = value.replace(/\s*\([0-9]+\)/, "");
    $("option:selected").html(new_value);
} );
```

​
http://jsfiddle.net/fdrGV/

Comment: How is the textarea identified? I don't know the HTML structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select').on('change', function () {
    var _selected = $(this).find('option:selected'),
        _orig = _selected.text();

    var _index = _orig.indexOf(' (');
    _selected.text(_orig.substring(_index, ''));

});
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8dD9j/)